# How do I set the folder for storing file uploads using Commons FileUpload

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

How do I set to location of where to store file uploads on a TOMCAT server?

I am using `commons.fileupload` and as it stands I am able to store multiple `.tmp` files to `catalina_base/temp` however, my aim is to store the uploaded folders in their original form to `d:\\dev\\uploadservlet\\web\\uploads`

I know this question is vague but to be honest I've been working with servlets for such a short amount of time and I don't yet understand the big picture, any suggestions of code or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

My servlet code which handles the uploads is as follows:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    public static final long MAX_UPLOAD_IN_MEGS = 5;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            //This is the folder I want to use!!
            //String uploadFolder = "d:\\dev\\uploadservlet\\web\\uploads";

    boolean isMultipartContent = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (!isMultipartContent) {
        out.println("Upload unsuccessful<br/>");
        return;
    }

    out.println("The following was uploaded:<br/>");

    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();     
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    upload.setSizeMax(MAX_UPLOAD_IN_MEGS * 1024 * 1024);


    TestProgressListener testProgressListener = new TestProgressListener();
    upload.setProgressListener(testProgressListener);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("testProgressListener", testProgressListener);

    try {
        List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
        out.println("Number of fields: " + fields.size() + "<br/><br/>");
        Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();
        if (!it.hasNext()) {
            out.println("No fields found");
            return;
        }
        out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            FileItem fileItem = it.next();
            boolean isFormField = fileItem.isFormField();
            if (isFormField) {
                out.println("<td>regular form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() + 
                        "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString()
                        );
                out.println("</td>");
            } else {
                out.println("<td>file form field</td><td>FIELDNAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() +//                     <br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString() +
                        "<br/>NAME: " + fileItem.getName() +
                        "<br/>CONTENT TYPE: " + fileItem.getContentType() +
                        "<br/>SIZE (BYTES): " + fileItem.getSize() +
                        "<br/>TO STRING: " + fileItem.toString()
                        );
                out.println("</td>");
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

...and it get's it's information from this HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Upload Page</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="uploadFunctions.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" action="test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield1" value="ok">
            <h3>Files to upload:</h3>
            <input type="file" size="50" name="file1">
            <span id="file1Progress">-</span>
            <br/>
            <a href="javascript:previewFile(1)">Preview</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <input type="file" size="50" name="file2">
            <span id="file2Progress">-</span>
            <br/>
            <a href="javascript:previewFile(2)">Preview</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <input type="file" size="50" name="file3">
            <span id="file3Progress">-</span>
            <br/>
            <a href="javascript:previewFile(3)">Preview</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <input type="file" size="50" name="file4">
            <span id="file4Progress">-</span>
            <br/>
            <a href="javascript:previewFile(4)">Preview</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <input type="file" size="50" name="file5">
            <span id="file5Progress">-</span>
            <br/>
            <a href="javascript:previewFile(5)">Preview</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" value="Upload" id="submitButton" onclick="uploadForm.submit();doProgress();">
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </form>

        <div class="progBar">                
            File number: <span id="fileText">-</span> is being uploaded.<br/> 
            <br/>
            <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress><br/>
            Upload of all files is: <span id="progressText">-</span>% complete.<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the desired location into [`FileItem#write()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) method the usual way as described in the Apache Commons FileUpload's own [users guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html).

First initialize the upload folder in the `init()` of your servlet.

```
private File uploadFolder;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    uploadFolder = new File("D:\\dev\\uploadservlet\\web\\uploads");
}
```

*(you can if necessary get this information from an environment variable or a properties file)*

Then extract the base name and extension from the filename of the uploaded file and generate an unique filename based on it (you of course don't want that a previously uploaded file get overwritten when someone else by coincidence uploads a file with the same name, right?):

```
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName());
String fileNamePrefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName) + "_";
String fileNameSuffix = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
File file = File.createTempFile(fileNamePrefix, fileNameSuffix, uploadFolder);
fileItem.write(file);
System.out.println("File successfully saved as " + file.getAbsolutePath());
// ...
```

*(note that the [`File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) doesn't necessarily mean that it's a temporary file which will be auto-deleted at some time, no, it's in this particular case just been used as a tool in order to generate a file with a guaranteed unique filename in the given folder)*

The [`FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) is provided by Apache Commons IO which you should already have installed as it's a dependency of Commons FileUpload.

---

Note that you should absolutely not set it as 2nd argument of [`DiskFileItemFactory`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html) constructor as suggested by the other answer. This represents, as clearly mentioned in its javadoc, the temporary disk file system location to store uploaded files when they exceed the threshold size (i.e. when they become too large to hold entirely in server's memory). This location is absolutely not intented as a permanent storage location for uploaded files. It will be auto-cleaned up at intervals by Commons FileUpload.

Comment: Just replace the current catch block by `catch (Exception e) { throw new ServletException(e); }`

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen javadoc of `DiskFileItemFactory`? There is a method [`setRepository`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html#setRepository%28java.io.File%29)  which takes `File` argument (folder where temp files will be stored).

So try this:

```
    FileItemFactory factory = 
       new DiskFileItemFactory(DiskFileItemFactory.DEFAULT_SIZE_THRESHOLD, 
                               new File("d:\\dev\\uploadservlet\\web\\uploads"));
```

And when you parsing form fields, you can save this files wherever you want.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I can now upload files where I please.

Comment: @jazibobs Do you want to not store .tmp files after uploading? You can use class `org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaningTracker`.

Comment: This is not the correct approach. The `repository` argument represents the local disk file system storage location for uploaded files whose size exceeds the default threshold. This is thus a temporary location and not a permanent location! This location will be cleaned up at intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You are using FileUpload to manage your upload. so In your code, you just define a file and write the data to it. I will copy only the relevant part and add to it :

```
if (isFormField) {
                out.println("<td>regular form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() + 
                        "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString()
                        );
                out.println("</td>");
            } else {

              //write the file
              String myPath= ..... 
              File f=new File(myPath);
              fileItem.write(f); 

                out.println("<td>file form field</td><td>FIELDNAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() +//                     <br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString() +
                        "<br/>NAME: " + fileItem.getName() +
                        "<br/>CONTENT TYPE: " + fileItem.getContentType() +
                        "<br/>SIZE (BYTES): " + fileItem.getSize() +
                        "<br/>TO STRING: " + fileItem.toString()
                        );
                out.println("</td>");
            }
```

IMPORTANT: make sure you have write permission to the folder where you write the file.

Comment: A.J, I attempted using your solution too but unfortunately the file did not upload to the folder as required. It may be a permissions issue but I managed to get Sergey's solution working so I'm going to run with that. Thank you for your time anyway! :)

Comment: you are most welcome and happy you found a solution that works. in the end, that is what matters. and no effort goes in vain. it might be useful for someone else in the future. thank you :)