# best approach to implement getRealPath()

Tags: servlets, struts2

I am working on struts 2.0 . I am designing a web application.
I am using Jasper Report in my application. I want to access the `*.jrxml` files in my action class. I don't want to give hard coded path to the files. So to get the path dynamically I googled it and got the solution that I can get the path using `getRealPath()` method. But I found two implementation of doing this:

1. Using `HttpSession` to get object of `ServletContext` and using the `getRealPath()` method of the `ServletContext` object. 
   Like this:

   ```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   String realPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
   ```
2. The second approach to do it directly using the static method `getServletContext()` of `ServletActionContext`. And then we can get the real path of the application using the `getRealPath()` method. 
   Like this:

   `String realPath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`

Please tell me, is there any difference between the above two and also please tell me whether there is any other way to get the path?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-function-servletcontext-getrealpath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843615/servlet-failing-to-write-uploaded-image-to-disk

Comment: Why don't you put your files in the webapp?

Comment: @AleksandrM These files are in my webapp. But There are three places where we deploy our application. localhost to develop and test the application, then demos server of our company and the live server. And if I give the hard coded path of the `/WebContent/reports/` location then I have to change it every time when I deploy it to the server accordingly. And I want a way, so that I do not need to change it every time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18181296/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is "better", really, and I'd argue that neither is particularly good, either.

I might try getting the context path in an initialization servlet and stick it into the application context, then make your action(s) `ApplicationAware` and retrieve the value from the map.

This has the added benefit of aiding testability and removing the static references in the action.

That said, I see zero reason to go through the extra mechanics of your first approach: it adds a lot of noise for no perceivable benefit; I'm not even sure why it wuld be considered.

I'd also be a little wary of tying your actions to a path like this unless there's a real need, what's the specific use? In general you shouldn't need to access intra-app resources by their path.

Comment: I am using JasperReports in my application, the path is required to access the jasper files in action class and also i am using the path  string as field, so that I can access the images required for the report. All I am doing is to avoid giving the static path.