# Convert FileItem to File

Tags: java, file, servlets, filestream, fileitem

I'm trying to upload a XML file (text.xml) using a simple upload html form, regulary read it as FileItem in the servlet and then get the ACTUAL file (text.xml) so i can print it, save it etc. Is there any educated way to do this simply? some people told me to use FileItem's property getInputStream.. is there any example somewhere? isn't there a shorter way?

thanks

Comment: Read/Writing streams too complicated?

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`FileItem#write()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#write%28java.io.File%29) method, exactly as demonstrated in [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) of [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload).

```
File file = new File("/path/to/text.xml");
fileItem.write(file);
```

That's all.

#### See also:

- [How do I set the folder for storing file uploads using Commons FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528081/how-do-i-set-the-folder-for-storing-file-uploads-using-commons-fileupload/13532453#13532453)
- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)